# Inherit the permissions on to the subfolders

Tags: linux

I want to create a directory, for instance testing-data on CentOS 6.5 Linux version, and have read,write,execute to all the sub-folders and sub-sub-folders and files within them to everyone(all users), not to any specific group.
In fact, whenever a new file is written into any of these sub-folders without using `chmod 777` the new file should be able to be accessed by any user.

Is this possible?

Comment: World writable (and executable!) files, while possible, are generally undesirable, as they present a significant security risk to all users on the system. What is the use-case for this requirement?

Comment: @derobert the question or the answer? The answer covers both `g+s` and ACLs, and the question doesn't know about `g+s`.

Comment: @muru Oh! It does, somehow I missed the ACL discussion in the answer. It is indeed a duplicate then.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. `umask` or `setfacl` both can do this.

```
sudo mkdir /everyone                #create the folder   
sudo chmod 777 /everyone            #to grant access for everyone to the folder
sudo setfacl -m d:m::rwx       #set file access control list
```

Added the `d` option to set default ACL - all the new files will have the default permissions.
And `umask` can help as well.